# Как принять данные на сервере методом POST с одинаковым ключом массива?

Tags: php, javascript

На странице есть фильтр. В этом фильтре я могу выбрать несколько свойств, например показать товары, которые имеют цвет: белый, красный, синий.

Я отправляю Ajax запрос на сервер:

```
var data = {
color: ["white","red", "blue"]
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function (results) { console.log(results) },
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional: true
});
```

На сервере мне нужно принять эти данные:

```
$color = $_POST['color'];
```

Отобразится последний из списка этих цветов - `blue`.

Как принять данные методом POST так, чтобы получить весь массив цветов?

Спасибо!

P.s. Нашел одно из решений самостоятельно. Данные можно получить в виде строки:

```
 $post = file_get_contents('php://input');   //color=white&color=red&color=blue
```

Comment: Чтобы `получить ... массив`, наверное, надо и передавать массив?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, Да, вы правы! Поправил!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("test.php", {
    color: ["white", "red", "blue"]
});

var_dump($_POST['color']);

/*
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(5) "white"
  [1]=> string(3) "red"
  [2]=> string(4) "blue"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Отправлять таким url

```
url: 'test.php?color[]=white&color[]=red&color[]=blue'
```

Тогда на сервере `$_POST['color']` будет массивом

Comment: а есть ли способы без скобок?

Comment: Если вам нужно получить массив, то вам нужно передать масив. По другому никак. Или передавать строкой с разделителем, а на сервере дергать `explode()`. А чем скобки не угодили?

Comment: Есть сайт, где это работает. Интересно как реализовали!

Comment: Вы уверены,что на сервере там PHP?

Comment: Не уверен, потому и спросил, может есть какие-то способы. С другой стороны, мне кажется, принцип обработки POST запроса у разных языков примерно одинаковый. Может быть я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Любой запрос - это передача каких-то служебных заголовков. Как эти заголовки интерпретируются сервером - это его личное дело. Может кто-то складывает одинаковые параметры в массив. Посмотрите, что выводит `var_dump($_SERVER)`. Может что-то найдете

Comment: К сожалению, если использовать POST,  то в $_SERVER ничего не попадает.  Только если использовать url с параметрами, то есть строка в ключе QUERY_STRING.

Comment: Накопал, что можно получить необработанные данные таким образом $post = file_get_contents('php://input'); Не знаю, насколько правильно, но в моем случае работает, получается строка color=white&color=red&color=blue

Answer (score 0):

> Как принять данные методом POST так, чтобы получить весь массив цветов?

Вот так отправить с клиента:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var ar = ['red', 'blue', 'green']; // Ваш массив
    $.ajax({
      // Для примера jsonplaceholder
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', // здесь ваш test.php
      // оберка в JSON
      data: {
        colors: ar, 
      },
      type: "POST",
      success: function(results) {
        console.info(results)
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      traditional: true
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="">Send</button>
```

И принять так в **test.php**:

```
$colors = json_decode($_POST['colors']);
```